# path not found in powershell job

Tags: powershell

Database testmssqldbnew is now removed from the instance

```
Cannot find path 'U:\UserDB\DBBACKUPS\testmssqldbnew_backup' because it does not exist.
At C:\Users\e2cauto1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\jenkins3940685503718462410.ps1:156 char:1
+ Invoke-Command -ComputerName $instance  -ArgumentList $path -ScriptBl ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (U:\UserDB\DBBAC...sqldbnew_backup:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundEx 
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : seliiwsql01.rnd.ericsson.se
 
Build step 'Windows PowerShell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am getting above error while running the script.

I want to cancel this step as I dont find any such path in my machine

**U:\UserDB\DBBACKUPS\testmssqldbnew_backup**

**The script I am using**

}
Write-Host " "
"Database $database is now removed from the instance"
}

`Write-Host " "

$file=$database+'_backup'

$path="U:\UserDB\DBBACKUPS$file"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $instance  -ArgumentList $path -ScriptBlock {

param($path)

#Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Remove-Item #-Recurse -ErrorAction Stop

Remove-Item -Path $path -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop

}

"Backup file $file is now deleted"`

But when I try to remove the last step to remove path I am  getting some other error. I am new to powershell. Small help can be appreciated

I am expecting to cancel the last step of removal of path

Write-Host " "

$file=$database+'_backup'

$path="U:\UserDB\DBBACKUPS$file"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $instance  -ArgumentList $path -ScriptBlock {

param($path)

#Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Remove-Item #-Recurse -ErrorAction Stop

Remove-Item -Path $path -Recurse -ErrorAction Stop

}

"Backup file $file is now deleted"

Is it okay If I just remove these lines

Comment: Your script starts with a `}`? No wonder it isn't working :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I optimized your script a little. Also I added a condition that checks if the path exists, because your error message reads like the directory doesn't exist.

With the cmdlet you were struggling with, there's a known issue with Remove-Item when using the Recurse parameter.

[image: known issue from MS learn]

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.3

So your script should look something like this:

```
Write-Output "Database $database is now removed from the instance`n"

$file = $database + '_backup'

$path = "U:\UserDB\DBBACKUPS$file"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $instance -ScriptBlock {
    if (Test-Path $using:path) {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $using:path -Recurse | Remove-Item
    }
}

Write-Output "Backup file $file is now deleted"
```